# Determining whether given functions are uniformly convergent - Solution Feedback

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

Working through *Spivak's Calculus - Ch 24 - 2) (i) and (ii)*, I've been asked to determine whether the following functions converge pointwise and to determine if they are uniformly convergent. The functions are:

**i)** $f_{n}(x) = x^{n} - x^{2n}$ on $[0,1]$

**ii)** $f_{n}(x) = \frac{nx}{1 + n + x}$ on $[0, \infty)$

Hints were given to solve the expressions and they are the following:

[image]

So solving **(i)**. The first thing to observe after a little playing around is that:

$$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) = 0$$

Now using the hint one works out that the maximum of $|f-f_{n}|$ on $[0,1]$ occurs when:

$$x = \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}}$$

If you plug this value into the expression of $|f(x) - f_{n}(x)|$ it will always work out to be:

$$|\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}| = \frac{1}{4}$$ for all values of $n$. From this I concluded that the sequence of functions does not converge uniformly to $f(x)$ because there will always be a distance of $\frac{1}{4}$ between the sequence and $f(x) = 0$.

So now working on (ii) with some fiddling around again one can conclude that:

$$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}(x) = x$$

Now using the hint given one works out:

$$\bigg|\frac{nx}{1+n+x} - x \bigg| \Rightarrow \bigg|\frac{-1(x^{2} + x)}{1 + n + x}\bigg| =  \frac{(x^{2} + x)}{1 + n + x}$$

Now here is where my question lies. I was going to conclude that this illustrates that the sequence of functions does converge uniformly. I was basing this off of the fact that the distance between $f_{n}$ and $f(x)$ will always be dependent on $n$ and as $n \to \infty$ my expression will go to $0$ (i.e. the distance between $f(x)$ and $f_{n}(x)$). This was the reasoning I used behind why **(i)** does not uniformly converge because the distance is not dependent on $n$ and is instead always constant.

Looking at the solutions my conclusion for **(ii)** is wrong. I wanted to know why that is the case and I also wanted to know if my reasoning for why **(i)** is not uniformly convergent is the right approach as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your distance depends on $x$. It is not true that you can make it uniformly small (by choosing $n$ large) for all $x\ge 0$. If you assume that you can make the distance say less than $1$ for $n\ge N>2$, you get a contradiction for $x=N$, where the distance is greater than $N/2>1$.

Comment: So using that reasoning, for (i) let's say that instead of the constant $\frac{1}{4}$ as my difference say for whatever reason the difference worked out to be: $\frac{1}{4^{n}}$. Under that condition then the sequence would have uniformly converged?  Also how did you work out $\frac{N}{2} > 1$? I did get a contradiction, but I plugged $N$ into $\frac{(x^{2} + x)}{1 + n + x} < 1$ and got a contradiction of $N<1$ and $N<0$ which of course can't occur based on assuming $N>2$.

Comment: If the sup-difference had been $1/4^n$ your sequence would be uniformly convergent, because it only depends on $n$ and goes to zero as $n\to\infty$. My choice of $x=N$ was one of many possible. First, you can assume that $N>2$ because if what we assert is true for $n\ge 1$ it will be certainly true for $n\ge N_0$ for $N_0\ge 1$. I chose $x=N$ because the obtained expression for the distance is roughly linear in $N$ . Your distance would be $(N^2+N)/(1+2N)=N(1+N)/(1+2N)>N/2>1$, contradicting the choice $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for your help